# adding optional key word arguments to discord bot commands

Tags: discord.py

I have a a bot command that I'd like to add an optional key word argument to, and i'd like some advice on it.

The command is:

```
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def repeat(ctx, *lines):
    print("repeating")
    await asyncio.gather(*[ctx.send(line) for line in lines])
```

So far, if you type in !repeat "1" "2" "3", it will respond:
1
2
3

I'd like to add the optional key word argument "repeats", which you could add after the innitial command, and it will tell the bot to repeat its response a specified number of times.

E.g. if you type in !repeat "1" "2" "repeats=2", it will respond:
1
2
1
2

but if you don't include the keyword it will work as normal

---

EDIT:
This is just a toy example. Quite often with functions- you want to let an advanced user do something unusual with kwargs without making all users interact with with those features. I'm interested in finding a way this could be done with a discord command that already takes any number of arguments.

Is there a way of adding the extra functionality without waking it so that every user has to interact with it by passing it as the first variable or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfornatelly `kwargs` don't work with `discord.py`, you'd need to put it as the first arg

```py
async def repeat(ctx, repeats: commands.Greedy[int] = 1, *lines):
    print("Repeating...")

    for i in range(repeats):
        for line in lines:
            await ctx.send(line) # You can also use your method with `asyncio.gather`
```

I'm using `commands.Greedy` so errors are silently ignored

To invoke it:

```
!repeat 10 hello there!
# or
!repeat hello there!
```

Also if you want it to repeat the whole `lines` in one message:

```py
async def repeat(ctx, repeats: commands.Greedy[int] = 1, *, message: str):
    print("Reperating...")

    for i in range(repeats):
        await ctx.send(message)
```

EDIT:

So basically what's happening when you invoke the command like this

```
!repeat 2 5 apples
```

`commands.Greedy` will convert it to a list like this: `[2, 5]`

We don't want that, here's a solution

```py
async def repeat(ctx, repeats: commands.Greedy[int] = 1, *, message):
    if isinstance(repeats, list):
        repeats = repeats[0]
        message = ' '.join(repeats[1:]) + message

    for i in range(repeats):
        await ctx.send(message)

# Another solution using `typing`
import typing

async def repeat(ctx, repeats: typing.Optional[int] = 1, *, message):
    for i in range(repeats):
        await ctx.send(message)
```

#### Reference:

- [`commands.Greedy`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=greedy#discord.ext.commands.Greedy)

Comment: when i try and do that i get this error 
"NameError: name 'Greedy' is not defined"
do you have any idea why?

Comment: Did you copy the code exactly like I wrote it? Make sure it's `commands.Greedy`

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I've now got greedy working - but there is still a kink with this. If i write $repeat a b I get the desired output. If i write $repeat2 5 a b I get a series of errors that seem to originate with discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer I've played around with speechmarks in the discord messages but haven't seen a way of making this work.

Comment: ahh, yes! I know why’s that, I’ll edit my answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: I did a small research, maybe [this](https://pypi.org/project/discord-flags/) module can help

Comment: Thanks so much! Really appreciate the response. I'm now reading about typing - i think I'm probably going to use this in the final piece of code that this was exploring.

Comment: haha no worries! I could have thought about typing before, my bad!

Answer (score -1):

For that, you have to add this argument before the `lines` argument. Also, you don't have to use `asyncio.gather`. You can just use strings.

```py
@bot.command(name='repeat', help='help me to understand bots')
async def repeat(ctx, repeat=1, *lines):
    print("repeating")
    msg = ' '.join(lines)*repeat
    await ctx.send(msg)
```